# With Play framework what am I doing wrong in setting up my routers

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-evolutions

I'm a newbie to Play and Scala (version 2.6) and I can't figure out how to get the routing to work in a simple fashion. Cobbling together examples from the 2.6 documentation I've manage to create a custom application loader, which I understand is required to perform Evolutions migrations. The example I found included a var router = Routes.empty The BuiltInComponentsFromContext appears to require a router to be used, but in doing so, with the way I've done it my routes are now broken and now all I get are "Action Not Found" messages.

Here is my application.conf:

```
play.application.loader=MyApplicationLoader
router = my.application.Router
```

Here is the Application Loader

```
import play.api.ApplicationLoader
import play.api.ApplicationLoader.Context
import play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext
import play.api.db.{Database, DBComponents, HikariCPComponents}
import play.api.db.evolutions.EvolutionsComponents
import play.api.routing.Router
import play.filters.HttpFiltersComponents
//import com.softwaremill.macwire._

class MyApplicationLoader extends ApplicationLoader {
  def load(context: Context) = {
    new MyComponents(context).application
  }
}

class MyComponents(cntx: Context)
  extends BuiltInComponentsFromContext(cntx)
    with DBComponents
    with EvolutionsComponents
    with HikariCPComponents
    with HttpFiltersComponents
{
  // this will actually run the database migrations on startup
  //lazy val router = Router.empty
  val router = Router.empty
  applicationEvolutions
}
```

It looks to me by declaring:

```
val router = Router.empty
```

I'm essentially invalidating any of the routes I've declared in my conf/routes file, and it occurs to me to use the Router.load method, but I can't find an example of how to pass the required environment and configuration values to the method.  Assuming I don't want to use static routes how do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you only use compile-time dependency injection just for the sake of the Evolutions (because otherwise you'd faced the same problems earlier), the answer is that you don't have to do that. Evolutions work with the default dynamic dependency injection as well. [The part of the documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/Evolutions#Running-evolutions-using-compile-time-DI) you probably basing your assumptions on actually says that ***if*** you are ***already*** using the compile-time dependency injection, here is how to modify it to make evolutions work. If you look at the source code of the [EvolutionsModule](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/683dc2c65d5daa463a3ffe2fb56157228cb8db8b/framework/src/play-jdbc-evolutions/src/main/scala/play/api/db/evolutions/EvolutionsModule.scala#L21) you may see that `ApplicationEvolutions` is bound [eagerly](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaDependencyInjection#Eager-bindings). It means that an instance of `ApplicationEvolutions` will be created at the start of the app during application initialization. And in the source code of the [`ApplicationEvolutions`](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/af76e3f60d1aa9e71ee29161b33dd6a8101bad71/framework/src/play-jdbc-evolutions/src/main/scala/play/api/db/evolutions/ApplicationEvolutions.scala#L154) itself you can see that `start()`  is called from the constructor. So if you provided configuration, the rest should work on its own.

Comment: @JohnL, if it helps, feel free to mark it as the Accepted answer